# ng-pattern becomes invalid when ng-required value changes

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern, ng-required

I have the following html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id, item) in $ctrl.items">
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.minRange" ng-pattern="$ctrl.ipPattern"
           name="{{$index}}_minRange"  />
    <div ng-messages="$ctrl.form[$index + '_minRange'].$error"
         ng-show="$ctrl.form[$index + '_minRange'].$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">Ips are required</div>
        <div ng-message="pattern">IP address is not valid</div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.maxRange" ng-pattern="$ctrl.ipPattern"
           name="{{$index}}_maxRange" ng-required="item.minRange" />
    <div ng-messages="$ctrl.form[$index + '_maxRange'].$error"
         ng-show="$ctrl.form[$index + '_maxRange'].$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">Ips are required</div>
        <div ng-message="pattern">IP address is not valid</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

The controller contains:

```
$ctrl.ipPattern = new RegExp('^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$|^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$', 'g');
$ctrl.items = //array of items containing minRange, maxRange and description.
```

The scenario that causes the error is the following:

I enter a valid IP to the maxRange, then I enter a valid IP to minRange. When the input of minRange becomes a valid pattern, the maxRange becomes invalid pattern some why. If I enter the same value again, it will work.

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: I have a lot of code that contains the save functionality. Only related code was attached and item description.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce: https://plnkr.co/edit/UTznJqjmmg5gAqdOp54Q?p=preview. Post a plunkr reproducing the problem.